# Add array values to ArrayList

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I have an arrayList and I want to populate it with some values. 
the problem is that this array list gets only the last value of array at the end. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are doing it into foreach and every time the RESTEndpoints receive a new value, so in this case RESTEndpoints get the last value always.

You have to change to this following code:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
        RESTEndpoints.addAll((ArrayList<RESTEndpoint>) new Gson().fromJson(sp.getString(entry.getKey(), "[]"), type));
}
```

Comment: Error:(38, 26) error: no suitable method found for addAll(Object)

Comment: You have to convert the object like  `RESTEndpoints.addAll((ArrayList<RESTEndpoint>) new Gson().fromJson(sp.getString(entry.getKey(), "[]"), type));`

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding to the arraylist

Change

```
RESTEndpoints = new Gson().fromJson(sp.getString(entry.getKey(), "[]"), type);
```

To

```
RESTEndpoints
.add(new Gson().fromJson(sp.getString(entry.getKey(), "[]"), type));
```

Comment: Error:(39, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(Object)

Comment: this is happening because Your  new Gson().fromJson(sp.getString(entry.getKey(), "[]"), type) object is not of RESTEndpoints type. please check your code

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding array values to your list, change the code as given below :

```
for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
    RESTEndpoints.addAll(new Gson().fromJson(sp.getString(entry.getKey(), "[]"), type));
    }
```

Comment: Error:(38, 26) error: no suitable method found for addAll(Object)
method ArrayList.addAll(int,Collection<? extends RESTEndpoint>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method ArrayList.addAll(Collection<? extends RESTEndpoint>) is not applicable
(actual argument Object cannot be converted to Collection<? extends RESTEndpoint> by method invocation conversion)
method AbstractList.addAll(int,Collection<? extends RESTEndpoint>) is not applicable